# Compiling linux module

Tags: linux-kernel

I've got homework in Operating Systems course, in which I have to write some module. We use Red Hat 8.0 with customed linux kernel 2.4.18.14. I have a makefile for compiling the module, but I fail getting it to work. the module source code is in snake.c and the makefile is:

```
KERNELDIR = /usr/src/linux-2.4.18-14custom
include $(KERNELDIR)/.config
CFLAGS = -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE –I$(KERNELDIR)/include -O -Wall
all: snake.o
```

The files are in directory /home/user/OS4.
When I call make command in that directory it write error:

```
cc: cannot specify -o with -c or -S and multiple compilations
```

Can You help me with it?
And I'll be glad if you'll explain how the modules compiling work.
Thanks

Comment: There is no gcc invokations in code you presented. Try `make -n` to get compiler command lines for each file and try to find invokation which has incorrect options (`-o` with `-c`, etc).

Comment: I don't understand whats the problem. the command line I get is:
cc -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE  ?I/usr/src/linux-2.4.18-14custom/include -Wall      -c -o snake.o snake.c
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cc -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE ?I/usr/src/linux-2.4.18-14custom/include -Wall -c -o snake.o snake.c
```

Note question mark before `I` letter. The problem is that instead of normal ascii *hyphen-minus* `-` (ASCII code: 45), you accidentally got *en dash* `–` (Unicode 0x2013) -- note that line is little longer.

It is coming from `CFLAGS` variable:

```
# CFLAGS = -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE –I$(KERNELDIR)/include -O -Wall
                                 ^^^ This is en dash
```

Replace it by regular hyphen <kbd>-</kbd> and you should be fine.

(and because this argument doesn't begin with `-`, gcc treats it not as option but extra source file but `-c` option does not allow to pass more than one source file)